# Change items in list and sort then list

Tags: java, list

I would like to access a list of objects and change some of the values inside the list. Afterwards i would like to sort the list according to date. Is it possible to do this and how do I go about doing this?

This is my code:

```
public class AccountTransactions {
    private int transactionID;
    private int transactionCode;
    private String transactionDate;
    private String transactionType;
    private String transactionTime;
    private String transactionAmount;
    private String transactionTo;
    private String transactionFrom;

    ... // for bravety

}
```

`Transactions.java`:

```
  public  ListtransactionsObjects getUserTransactions(SearchbyPublicKeyObject publicKeyObject){

        List<AccountTransactions> transactionFrom =  TransactionsRepository.findByTransactionFrom(publicKeyObject.getPublicKey());
        List<AccountTransactions> transactionTo = TransactionsRepository.findByTransactionTo(publicKeyObject.getPublicKey());



  //sudo code
  // loop through list 
  // transactionTo.transactionAmount = "+" + transactionAmount



        List<AccountTransactions> AllTransactions = Stream.concat(transactionFrom.stream(), transactionTo.stream())
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }



 // sort AllTransactions by transactionDate which is of type 05/06/2018
```

Comment: Loop through your list and change wanted objects, after you're done make custom `Comparator` if default one for `Date` doesn't satisfy what you need and sort the list accordingly.

Comment: Write a comparator and Collections.sort()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traverse the objects in the loop and set values. Then use comparator.

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<AccountTransactions>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(AccountTransactions o1, AccountTransactions o2) {

          return o1.getTransactionDate().compareTo(o2.getTransactionDate());
        }  
    });
```

Make transactionDate of Date type.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Collections.sort` as

```
// sort AllTransactions by transactionDate which is of type 05/06/2018
Collections.sort(AllTransactions, AccountTransactions::getTransactionDate);
```

Assuming you should have `getTransactionDate` in `AccountTransactions` that returns your transaction `date` (not the `string` which you have).
You may have to convert your `string` to `date.`